# Expectation of a factorial of a random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to solve a question pertaining to the quantity $$E(N!)$$ which is the expectation of a random variable factorial.

Basically I would like to construct a non-negative discrete random variable $N$ such that $E(N!)<\infty$ while the quantity $$\| X\|_\infty = \sup\{t\ge 0: P(X\ge t)>0\}=\infty.$$

Basically, I need $N$ to barely assign mass to any of the integers since $N!$ can get very very large, but at the same time I dont want the mass to be negligible since I will require that $P(X\ge t)\not\to0$ as $t\to\infty$.

I do not really know how to start this. I have tried $P(N=n)=2^{-n!}$ and similar, but this does not work either.

Comment: Actually setting $P(N=n)=c2^{-n!}$ (where $c$ is chosen so they sum to $1$) does work.

Comment: "I will require that $P(X\geq t) \not \to 0 $ as $t \to \infty$." You probably meant that $X$ is unbounded, but this is not how you say it. This condition isn't satisfied by any random variable. Unbounded variables are those which for any $t>0$ satisfy $P(|X| > t)>0$

Comment: @Esgeriath, you're right. Actually even unbounded is not enough here since $\|N\|=\infty$ is a stronger condition than unboundedness.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I can't seem to show that $\|N\|=\infty$.

Comment: For every $n$ you know that the probabilty that $N=n$ is positive - y definition this says $||N||_\infty\ge n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote $p_n=\mathbb P(N=n)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$; then $\mathbb E\left[N!\right]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n!p_n$. Therefore, we are reduced to find a sequence of positive numbers $\left(p_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n!p_n<\infty$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n=1$. Taking $$p_n= c\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)^2} \frac{1}{n!},$$ where $c=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)^2} \frac{1}{n!}\right)^{-1}$, does the job, or more generally, $p_n=K a_n/n!$, where $a_n>0$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n<\infty$ and
$K=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty   \frac{a_n}{n!}\right)^{-1}$.